# Отключить курсор мыши через консольное приложение C++

Tags: c++

Как в Console Application на c++ отключить курсор мышки (не каретку ввода) что бы ни клавиши ЛКМ ни ПКМ ни колесико не работало?

Пробую так :

```
    while (true)
    {
        if (_kbhit())
        {
            switch(_getch())
            {
                case  49 :
                printf("\r\nMouse was disabled!");
                ShowCursor(FALSE);
                SetCursor(NULL);
                break;

                case 50:
                printf("\r\nMouse enabled again!");
                ShowCursor(TRUE);
                break;

                case 51 :
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Никаких изменений.

Comment: `ShowCursor` управляет отображением, а не отключением. Есть `GetConsoleWindow` показывает окно консоли, возможно Hook на мышь этому окну позволит перехватить и отменить события мыши.

Comment: `BlockInput(TRUE)` блокирует и клавиатуру и мышь, есть метод для блокировки одной только мыши ?

Comment: При `GetConsoleWindow` мышь перестанет работать только в окне консоли ?

Comment: Попробуйте Hook на мышь поставить (без передачи по цепи).

Comment: Может попробуйте [SetConsoleMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms686033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: `SetConsoleMode` для консоли, а нужно в принципе блокировать все сигналы от мыши.

Comment: @nick_n_a спасибо, разобрался!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, что бы блокировать курсор мыши можно воспользоваться хуками.Благодарю за подсказку уважаемого  @nick_n_a.  Создаем консольное приложение на C++ с кодом:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
HINSTANCE hInstance;
HHOOK miHook;
void BlockMouseMovement();
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
if(nCode == HC_ACTION) 
    {
    MSLLHOOKSTRUCT &msll = *(reinterpret_cast<MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*>(lParam));
    if(wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN) 
        {
        // Do your logic here
        if(true)
             {
            return -1; // игнорирование кликов
             }
        }
    }
return CallNextHookEx(miHook, nCode, wParam, lParam); 
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 printf("if you want to disable the mouse press  key 1, if want to enable key 2");

    while (true)
    {
        if (_kbhit())
        {
            switch(_getch())
            {
                case  49 :
                printf("\r\nMouse was disabled!");
                SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, reinterpret_cast<HOOKPROC>(&LowLevelMouseProc), hInstance, 0);
                UnhookWindowsHookEx(miHook);

                break;
                case 51 :
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
_getch();
return 0;
}
```