# Блокировка действий мыши с помощью хука

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

Есть [консольное приложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/679538/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-c).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

HINSTANCE hInstance;
HHOOK miHook;
void BlockMouseMovement();

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
{
    MSLLHOOKSTRUCT &msll = *(reinterpret_cast<MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*>(lParam));
    if (wParam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        if (true)
        {
            return -1; 
        }
    }
}
return CallNextHookEx(miHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    {
    printf("if you want to disable the mouse press  key 1, if want to enable key 2");

    while (true)
    {
        if (_kbhit())
        {
            switch (_getch())
            {
            case  49:
                printf("\r\nMouse was disabled!");
                SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, reinterpret_cast<HOOKPROC>(&LowLevelMouseProc), hInstance, 0);
                UnhookWindowsHookEx(miHook);

                break;
                case 51:
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

}

Но этот код не работает. Подскажите, в чём ошибка.

P.S. После установки хука функция LowLevelMouseProc вообще не срабатывает, при любых действиях мышью.

Comment: Что делает `UnhookWindowsHookEx(miHook);`??? Также, почему третьим параметром передается `hInstance`?

Comment: Т.к. делал всё по примеру. Пробовал убирать и UnhookWindowsHookEx и вместо hInstace ставить 0 - не работает.

Comment: Надо делать не по примеру, а по документации, все параметры, кроме первого, неправильные. Проверка возвращаемого значения и обработка ошибок отсутствует.

Comment: Очевидно в `miHook` должен был сохраняться результат вызова `SetWindowsHookEx`. Однако у вас этого не делается. И, разумеется, сразу делать unhook нельзя. Где вы такой пример откопали?

Comment: Ссылка наверху. Подумал, что раз у кого-то сработало, то и у меня сработает. Мало знаком с WinAPI.