# Глобальный хук на мышь

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

Консольное приложение:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "Windows.h"

HHOOK myHook;

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (wParam >= 0)
    {
        if (wParam == WM_XBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            printf("X Button pressed.");
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(myHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    myHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, LowLevelMouseProc, hInstance, 0);    
    if (myHook != NULL)
        printf("Hook complited;");
    else
        printf("Hook not complited.");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема в том, что хук не работает.

Ткните пожалуйста меня носом в место, где не правильно, и, если не сложно, подскажите как правильно please.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Блокировка действий мыши с помощью хука](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/867779/%d0%91%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%88%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d1%85%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: Этот вопрос был добавлен по причине того, что в том вопросе не было конструктивного ответа для решения данной проблемы.

Comment: в чем выражается нерабочесть?

Comment: LowLevelMouseProc вообще не работает. Сообщение в консоль не выводит. Ставил breakpont в функции - код не работает. Хотя, если я правильно понимаю, при любых действиях от мыши данная функция должна работать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Для того, чтобы хуки группы `..._LL` работали (например `WH_MOUSE_LL`), ваш процесс должен обрабатывать очередь сообщений

   ```
   myHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, LowLevelMouseProc, 0, 0);    

   MSG msg;
   while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
   {
     TranslateMessage(&msg);
     DispatchMessage(&msg);
   }

   UnhookWindowsHookEx(myHook);
   ```
2. Прекратите указывать `hInstance` в вызове `SetWindowsHookEx`. В документации ясно сказано, что если обработчик хука находится в текущем процессе, то этот параметр должен быть `NULL`.
3. Что такое

   ```
   if (wParam >= 0)
   ```

   ? `WPARAM` - беззнаковый тип и такое сравнение бессмысленно. Скорее имелось в виду

   ```
   if (nCode >= 0)
   ```

   ибо при отрицательном `nCode` вы *обязаны* сразу вызвать `CallNextHookEx`.

Comment: Помогло, всё работает. На счёт 3-его пункта - да, я это имел ввиду, не то написал. Буду благодарен если вы объясните зачем нужно обрабатывать очередь сообщений и почему он без него не работал (или скинете ссылку на инфу).

Comment: @Llirik 21: "Обычные" хуки требуют отдельного DLL и отдельного потока, в котором и будет жить (и асинхронно вызываться) обработчик хука. Именно для этого и нужны последние два параметра `SetWindowsHookEx`. А вот хуки группы `_LL` работают по-другому - они живут и вызываются в вашем родном потоке. В такой ситуации не существует никакого способа вызова хука, кроме как через диспетчер сообщений. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458807/why-must-setwindowshookex-be-used-with-a-windows-message-queue#7460728

Answer (score 1):

Как уже указал Ant, у вас нету обработчика сообщений, ниже пример где цикл обработки вынесен в поток

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "Windows.h"

HHOOK hMouseHook;

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT* pMouseStruct = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;

    if (pMouseStruct != NULL)
    {
        if (wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            printf("clicked");
        }
        printf("Mouse position X = %d  Mouse Position Y = %d\n", pMouseStruct->pt.x, pMouseStruct->pt.y);
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hMouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

DWORD WINAPI MyMouseLogger(LPVOID lpParm)
{
    hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, LowLevelMouseProc, NULL, 0);

    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hMouseHook);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HANDLE hThread = NULL;

    hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, MyMouseLogger, NULL, 0, NULL);

    if (hThread != NULL )
        return WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Пожалуйста, объясните зачем необходимо обрабатывать очередь сообщений.

Comment: @Llirik21, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632590(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Последний параметр `SetWindowsHookEx` имеет тип `DWORD`. Почему туда вдруг передается `NULL` в качестве аргумента? Та же история с `CreateThread`. Откуда берется эта странная манера использовать `NULL` в целочисленных контекстах?

Comment: @AnT, поправил где заметил, спасибо) откуда манера? - винапи располагает к говнокоду, GetMessage - возвращаемый тип BOOL, но в тоже время функция может возвращать -1, 0 и >0

Comment: @Llirik21, если собираетесь писать кейлоггер под винду, то почитайте книги об архитектуре ОС, например Руссиновича "Внутреннее устройство Microsoft Windows", там про очереди сообщений написано что зачем и как