# Как минимизировать использование процессора?

Tags: c++

Я написал простейший код для автоматического "продолжения клика" при удержании правой клавиши мыши. Код загружает процессор примерно на 24% после компиляции. При использовании загруженность возрастает примерно до 50-60%. Я подозреваю, что это связано с наличием цикла `while(true) {}`, который постоянно работает пока запущен код.

```
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)) {
            if (i < 15) {
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                i++;
            }
        }
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON)) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Каким образом можно заменить этот цикл тем самым минимизировав загруженность процессора?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По моему, самое простое, что можно сделать с Вашей программой, почти ничего в ней не меняя - это отправлять её "поспать" примерно 100 раз в секунду. Это делается в код дописыванием одной строки ( `Sleep(10);` ):

```
    #include <Windows.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)) {
                if (i < 15) {
                    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON)) {
                i = 0;
            }
            Sleep(10);
        }
    }
```

Конечно, есть гораздо более правильные способы сделать то, что Вы делаете - можно подписываться на определенные события от мыши и клавиатуры, но это потребует гораздо бОльших измненений.

Вообще, использование цикла `while(true){...}` - это довольно затратный способ сделать, чтобы программа "всё время работала".

**Дополнение, дополненное после вопроса "каким образом подписаться на события от мыши?".**

Смотрите, вопрос почти полностью раскрыт в таком вопросе: [Глобальный хук на мышь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/868654/) Но так как Вы делаете некотрые определенные вещи - повторяете мышиный клик несколько раз - то я позволил себе взять и немного модифицировать код из этого вопроса.

Чуть чуть теории.

Это называется "повесить хук". Вы говорите системе: *"я тут пойду погуляю, но когда что нибудь придёт от мышки - вызови воооо-н ту процедуру, окей?"*. Это делается методом `SetWindowsHookEx()`. Это, так сказать, "подписка на события от мыши".

Следующие два момента: во первых, Ваша программа должна классически обрабатывать очередь событий, без этого этот метод не работает. Во вторых, когда обработка хука закончилась (в процедуре `LowLevelMouseProc()`) - нужно вызвать следующий обработчик в цепочке: это делает `CallNextHookEx()`. Да, и всё это запускается из main'а в отдельном треде. Ну, так уж принято, как я понял. (Возможно, можно всё это запустить и в основном треде, вроде бы ничего этому не мешает)

Теперь сам код.

Чтобы реализовать ту штуку, которую делает Ваша программа - я добавил в этот код буквально пару строчек, а именнно:
добавил счетчик мышиных кликов, и добавил флаг, который говорит "это событие от мыши в очереди сгенерировано программно, не надо на него реагировать так же, как на настоящий клик по кнопке". Если бы этого флага не было - то каждый вызов `mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);` приводил бы к порождению нового события от мыши, которое обрабатывалось бы в этом же потоке...  в общем, если Вы уберете флаг - будьте готовы перезагрузить Windows кнопкой питания :-)

Надеюсь, так стало понятнее.

```
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    HHOOK hMouseHook;

    LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    DWORD WINAPI MyMouseLogger(LPVOID lpParm);



    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        HANDLE hThread = NULL;

        hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, MyMouseLogger, NULL, 0, NULL);

        if (hThread != NULL )
            return WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
        else
            return 1;
    }

    int process_event_flag = 0;

    DWORD WINAPI MyMouseLogger(LPVOID lpParm) {
        hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, LowLevelMouseProc, NULL, 0);
        process_event_flag = 1;

        MSG message;
        while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
        {
            TranslateMessage(&message);
            DispatchMessage(&message);
        }

        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hMouseHook);
        return 0;
    }

    size_t click_count = 0;

    LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT* pMouseStruct = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;

        if (pMouseStruct != NULL && process_event_flag==1 ) {
            if (wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
            {
                printf("clicked: %d times\n", ++click_count);
                // repeat 5 clicks without using
                process_event_flag = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    Sleep(10);
                    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    Sleep(10);
                }
                process_event_flag = 1;
            }
            
            printf("Mouse position X = %d  Mouse Position Y = %d\n", pMouseStruct->pt.x, pMouseStruct->pt.y);
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(hMouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Comment: Эээ... Простите, но разве `std::chrono::milliseconds(10000)` — это не 10 секунд? такая программа проспит все на свете :)

Comment: Я бы вообще виндовую функцию sleep использовал. Зачем тут тащить два заголовка и ещё ошибок наделать

Comment: @Harry, KoVadim - дорогие старшие товарищи, спасибо за терпеливые замечания! "Пьяный был, глупость написал" - сейчас исправил!

Comment: Да ладно, просто не хотелось лезть без спросу и исправлять явную описку...

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а Вы знаете каким образом "подписаться на события от мыши"? Никогда про такое не слышал, потому мне стало очень интересно ибо это в состоянии как-то оптимизировать данную ситуацию. В идеале желательно бы каким-то образом добиться использования процессора на уровне от 1 до 5 %, но мне ничего не приходит в голову кроме как что-то сделать с циклом.

Comment: @S.H. - теперь мы знаем, что наш анонимный минусатор с++ не знает:)

Comment: @KoVadim - я прошу прощения, "теперь мы знаем, что наш анонимный минусатор с++ не знает:)" - я понял, что это шутка, я даже могу согласиться, что я С++ не знаю, но я вроде никого анинимно не минусовал :-)

Comment: тут все глубже. у нас есть анонимный минусатор, который минусует вопросы по странной схеме. Если бы минусатор понимал с++, он явно бы минусанул этот вопрос.

Comment: @KoVadim привет. по какой схеме минусует?

Comment: находит вопросы, которые ему кажутся плохими и минусует.